# How to add padding on a video with text in foreground using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to add padding to video clip according to width and height of the text I input. The sentence should be able to break relative to video width automatically.

For padding I use:

```
ffmpeg -i d:\video.mp4 -vf pad=600:700:0:100:blue d:\videooutput.mp4
```

For text:

```
ffmpeg -i d:\videooutput.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/windows/fonts/BebasNeue.otf:text='Sed felis eros, ornate ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus.':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0" d:\videooutput2.mp4
```

How to do achieve this in a single command?

The required result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just sequence the filters in a single chain:

```
ffmpeg -i d:\video.mp4 -vf "pad=600:700:0:100:blue,drawtext=fontfile=/windows/fonts/BebasNeue.otf:text='Sed felis eros, ornate ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus.':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0" d:\videooutput.mp4
```